# Sonarqube installation error

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I installed sonarqube. It doesn't get the page. When I type url : http://localhost:9000   It shows like . site can't be reached connection was rest

I see this error in the log:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon Launching a JVM... Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.12.27 09:57:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2016.12.27 09:57:36 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
-cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process6944140383591632391properties
2016.12.27 09:57:43 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.12.27 09:57:43 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar
-cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process8199216027008777051properties
```

And this is the output of `netstat -ntl`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18618         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18619         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::43363                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50762/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-janos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize our [chatroom discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50762/discussion-between-antony-naveen-and-janos),
another program was using port 900,
therefore SonarQube could not be fully started.
To verify the running process on port 9000:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 9000
```

This also prints out the PID of the process.

After shutting down the process and restarting SonarQube, it worked.

Comment: I have got a problem.. I just make to install sonarqube-scanner. but it override old sonar file. so now 127.0.01:9000/sonar not working can you help me ?

Comment: I'm trouble to install sonar-scanner. please help me..